# file.readlines leaving blank lines

Tags: python, string, file-io

I have read that `file.readlines` reads the whole file line by line and stores it in a list.
If I have a file like so -

```
Sentence 1
Sentence 2
Sentence 3
```

and I use `readlines` to print each sentence like so -

```
file = open("test.txt") 
for i in file.readlines():
    print i
```

The output is

```
Sentence 1

Sentence 2

Sentence 3
```

My question is why do I get the extra line between each sentence and how can I get rid of it?

**UPDATE**

I found that using `i.strip` also removes the extra lines. Why does this happen? As far as I know, `split` removes the white spaces at the end and beginning of a string.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`file.readlines()` return list of strings. Each string contain trailing newlines. `print` statement prints the passed parameter with newlnie.; That's why you got extra lines.

To remove extra newline, use `str.rstrip`:

```
print i.rstrip('\n')
```

or use `sys.stdout.write`

```
sys.stdout.write(i)
```

BTW, don't use `file.readlines` unless you need all lines at once. Just iterate the file.

```
with open("test.txt") as f:
    for i in f:
        print i.rstrip('\n')
        ...
```

**UPDATE**

In Python 3, to prevent `print` prints trailing newline, you can use `print(i, end='')`.

In Python 2, you can use same feature if you do : [`from __future__ import print_function`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/__future__.html)

**Answer to UPDATE**

Tabs, Newlines are also considers as whitespaces.

```
>> ' \r\n\t\v'.isspace()
True
```

Comment: ...and then your print command is adding the second newline I guess

Comment: `rstrip("\n")` would be enough since the file was opened in text mode.

Comment: @TimPietzcker, You're right. I edited the answer according to your comment. Thank you.

Comment: Or, `print(i, end='')` if the OP is on Python 3; or `from __future__ import print_function` if on Python 2.x

Comment: Why were you doing `rstrip("\r\n")` ? There is no `\r` at the end of the sentence right ?

Comment: @Mayank, I updated answer. Maybe you are seeing old revision of the answer. `\r` will not appear unless you open the file with binary mode (`b`).

Answer (score 1):

```
file.readlines()
```

(and also `file.readline()`) includes the newlines.

Do

```
print i.replace('\n', '')
```

if you don't want them.

It may seem weird to include the newline at the end of the line, but this allows, for example, you to tell whether the last line has a newline character or not. That case in tricky in many languages' I/O.

Answer (score 1):

The below will strip the newline for you.

```
i = i.rstrip("\n") #strips newline
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This worked out for me with Python 3.
I found rstrip() function really useful in these situations

```
for i in readtext:
    print(i.rstrip())
```

Comment: Please add description

Comment: Hi, I am new to this.
May I ask how I can add description?

Answer (score 0):

```py
with open(txtname, 'r') as txtfile:
    lines = txtfile.readlines()
    lines = [j for j in lines if j != '\n']
with open(outname, 'w') as outfile:
    outfile.writelines(lines)
```